# Keeping a reference to a bean inside @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-bean

Can I keep a reference to an exposed bean inside the `@Configuration` class so that I can later on execute operations on that same bean? For example:

```
@Configuration
class MyBeanConfiguration extends DisposableBean {
  private MyBean myBean; // Correct?

  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean() {
    return (this.myBean = MyBeanFactory.newMyBean());
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() throws Exception {
    doSomethingWith(myBean);
  }
}
```

Will I run into any trouble with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You likely would run into trouble. Probably you don't want your `Configuration` class to extend `DisposableBean`, but rather have `MyBean` extend it and implement the `destroy` method in `MyBean`.

Alternately, you could configure a custom destroy method for `MyBean` like so: `@Bean(destroyMethod='mydestroy')` and that way `MyBean` class wouldn't have a hard dependency on Spring.

A third option would be to create a listener than implements `ApplicationListener<ContextClosed>` and autowire `MyBean` into that class and do something with it there.

Comment: What trouble is he likely to run into?

Comment: @meriton -- Well when would the `destroy` method get called in his original code example? Probably only when the application context is destroyed, not when the `Bean` itself is destroyed. Also, `Configuration` classes should be used as classes that *declare* beans not as beans themselves I think.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do the following without any issues:

```
@Configuration
class MyBeanConfiguration implements DisposableBean {

  private @Autowired MyBean myBean;

  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean() {
    return MyBeanFactory.newMyBean();
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() throws Exception {
    doSomethingWith(myBean);
  }

}
```

Note: I don't know if this is a bad approach, and I only do this when I am not in control of the `MyBean` class and cannot implement `DisposeableBean` there.